# Weird hygiene in macros

Tags: macros, julia, hygiene

Suppose I have this macro definition in a module:

```
module Example

export @example_macro

macro example_macro(a)
    quote
        local r = RemoteRef()
        put!(r, $(esc(a)))
        remotecall_fetch(2, (r) -> fetch(r), r)
    end
end

end
```

And here is its expansion:

```
julia> include("Example.jl")

julia> using Example

julia> macroexpand(quote @example_macro a end)
quote  # none, line 1:
    begin  # /.../Example.jl, line 7:
        local #121#r = Example.RemoteRef() # line 8:
        Example.put!(#121#r,a) # line 9:
        Example.remotecall_fetch(2,(r) -> Example.fetch(r),#121#r)
    end
end
```

Every single one of globally available functions (like `put!` or `fetch`) are prefixed with the name of the module. I understand that this is needed for the macro to be hygienic - if, say, `fetch` was redefined in the module in which `@example_macro` is called, and `fetch` was inserted into the expansion as is, it wouldn't work correctly.

However, this also requires `Example` module to be available not only in the main process, but also on the second worker (since `remotecall_fetch` needs to execute `Example.fetch` on it). I don't want it - after all, `fetch` is a basic function available on all workers by default.

So, is there a way to disable prefixing all identifiers with the name of the current module? I think this would mean turning the macro non-hygienic as it is impossible to decide where some identifier (like `fetch`) is defined on macro expansion phase, and that's fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a pretty profound question, I think that you should give the Julia devs themselves a chance to answer it by asking on [julia-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/julia-users).

Currently,  you can completely circumvent macro hygiene by wrapping the whole `quote` block in your macro in an `esc(...)` (don't forget to take away the `esc` around `a`), but I would in general advise against it - then you are on your own.

Comment: Nice, didn't know that `esc()` is "recursive"! Similar macro features in other languages like Clojure do not work like this. I'll wait some time for more answers and if there are none I'll accept yours. Thanks!